# Remote function causing form to not submit (Unobtrusive Ajax and MVC 4 form validation issue)

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

I have a form that is validated using unobtrusive validation in the MVC 4 framework.  I have a remote annotation over one of the fields in my View Model that seems to keep the form from submitting.  That indicates to me that something is not quite working right.  I can't seem to figure out what it is however?

```
    [Remote("ValidateHosFin", "EditEncounter", AdditionalFields = "HostpitalFinNumber, IsFlagSet", ErrorMessage = "Got Damn this is complex!")]
    [MinLength(6,ErrorMessage="The Hospital Fin must have 6 numerals")]
    public string HostpitalFinNumber { get; set; }
```

It should call this method... It never gets called though as the breakpoint that I set never gets hit...

```
    [HttpPost]
    [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public ActionResult ValidateHosFin(string hospitalFin, string encflag) {
        return Json(DataRepository.ValidateHosFin(encflag, hospitalFin), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is of course in the `public class EditEncounterController : Controller{ //... }`

One of the things that I think of immediately is that my input values are incorrect... But they seem fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking the HospitalFinNumber out of your AdditionalFields parameter.  This is already the subject of the Remote attribute, so will be sent automatically.  You're causing it to be sent twice, meaning it's looking for a method with three parameters.

Another thing ... MVC4 binding matches on field-name ... you're sending the additional field "IsFlagSet", but your method is looking for the field "encflag" ... these won't link up in a Remote call.